# AT Command For Overwriting ICCID Sim

Tags: gsm, at-command

Is it possible to overwrite a SIM card's ICCID number using AT commands? If so, what is the command for it?

If not possible via AT commands, is there another way to overwrite the ICCID of a sim card? USSD etc

Answer (score 2):

No, I'm afraid it is not possible.

ICCID number is physically written in the internal memory of the SIM itself.
As soon as the cellular modem/telephone is powered on:

- the SIM is resetted
- the ATR string is read (ATR = Answer To reset)
- the communication modem <-> SIM is configured

After that the SIM is just like some sort of "data array", in which you can read specific data at specific indexes. **One of them is ICCID number** and it is used for the SIM authentication on the network.

Whay it is not possible to change it? Well SIM stands for "**S**ubscriber **I**dentity **M**odule". Changing your ICCID number would mean adulterating its identity, and that would fail to fulfil SIM's own main purpose.

Comment: That makes total sense. Given the fact that a sim card is simply an MCU, do you think it would be possible with the proper circuit and code to re-flash that ID?

Comment: I don't think it would be possible, but even in case I'm afraid it would be illegal.. :)